# str_extract does not recognize Russian patterns

Tags: r, stringr

I have this data:

```
  library(tidyverse)
  t1 %>% head(5)
                           shop_name
1                Москва ТРК "Атриум"
2      !Якутск Орджоникидзе, 56 фран
3                     Омск ТЦ "Мега"
4               Самара ТЦ "ПаркХаус"
5 Москва ТЦ "Новый век" (Новокосино)
```

I want to extract certain patterns and add them to a new column.

```
t1 %>% 
mutate(location = str_extract(shop_name,"TPK|ТЦ|ТК|ТРЦ|МТРЦ|ТЦ"))
```

However, I just get NAs out of it. Any idea what´s the reason?

For other operations e.g. extracting the pattern between the quotation marks it works fine.

```
t1 %>%
mutate(name = str_extract(shop_name, '"\\D+"|"\\d+"'))
```

Here is a `dput()`:

```
structure(list(shop_name = c("Москва ТРК \"Атриум\"", "!Якутск Орджоникидзе, 56 фран", 
"Омск ТЦ \"Мега\"", "Самара ТЦ \"ПаркХаус\"", "Москва ТЦ \"Новый век\" (Новокосино)", 
"Тюмень ТЦ \"Гудвин\"", "Москва ТЦ \"Семеновский\"", "Казань ТЦ \"ПаркХаус\" II", 
"Интернет-магазин ЧС", "СПб ТК \"Сенная\"", "Ярославль ТЦ \"Альтаир\"", 
"СПб ТК \"Невский Центр\"", "Уфа ТК \"Центральный\"", "Красноярск ТЦ \"Взлетка Плаза\"", 
"Балашиха ТРК \"Октябрь-Киномир\"", "Химки ТЦ \"Мега\"", "Чехов ТРЦ \"Карнавал\"", 
"Якутск ТЦ \"Центральный\"", "Вологда ТРЦ \"Мармелад\"", "Воронеж (Плехановская, 13)", 
"Москва МТРЦ \"Афи Молл\"", "Воронеж ТРЦ \"Максимир\"", "Москва ТЦ \"МЕГА Теплый Стан\" II", 
"Якутск Орджоникидзе, 56", "РостовНаДону ТЦ \"Мега\"", "Москва ТЦ \"Перловский\"", 
"Москва ТЦ \"МЕГА Белая Дача II\"", "Сургут ТРЦ \"Сити Молл\"", 
"Тюмень ТЦ \"Зеленый Берег\"", "Курск ТЦ \"Пушкинский\"", "Уфа ТЦ \"Семья\" 2", 
"Красноярск ТЦ \"Июнь\"", "Москва ТЦ \"Ареал\" (Беляево)", "Н.Новгород ТРЦ \"Фантастика\"", 
"Калуга ТРЦ \"XXI век\"", "Волжский ТЦ \"Волга Молл\"", "Москва ТК \"Буденовский\" (пав.К7)", 
"Новосибирск ТЦ \"Мега\"", "Коломна ТЦ \"Рио\"", "Жуковский ул. Чкалова 39м?", 
"Сергиев Посад ТЦ \"7Я\"", "Москва Магазин С21", "Адыгея ТЦ \"Мега\"", 
"РостовНаДону ТРК \"Мегацентр Горизонт\"", "Мытищи ТРК \"XL-3\"", 
"Москва ТК \"Буденовский\" (пав.А2)", "Москва ТЦ \"Серебряный Дом\"", 
"Тюмень ТРЦ \"Кристалл\"", "Самара ТЦ \"Мелодия\"", "Томск ТРЦ \"Изумрудный Город\"", 
"!Якутск ТЦ \"Центральный\" фран", "Выездная Торговля", "Воронеж ТРЦ Сити-Парк \"Град\"", 
"Жуковский ул. Чкалова 39м<U+00B2>", "Н.Новгород ТРЦ \"РИО\"", 
"Новосибирск ТРЦ \"Галерея Новосибирск\"", "Казань ТЦ \"Бехетле\"", 
"РостовНаДону ТРК \"Мегацентр Горизонт\" Островной", "Цифровой склад 1С-Онлайн", 
"Москва \"Распродажа\"")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-60L))
```

Comment: Maybe change encoding first?

Comment: What do you mean? The encoding is `UTF-8`. I have to do it because it´s Russian. Otherwise, I get an output like this `<U+00B2>`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: If one of the pattern `TPK|ТЦ|ТК|ТРЦ|МТРЦ|ТЦ` is in the column shop_name they should be extracted and added to a new column called location. The column shop_name should remain. Now I try to use `t1 %>% mutate(location = str_extract(shop_name, '\\s\\D{2,4}\\s'))` but it´s not perfect yet.

Comment: Not directrly related but do you know what ТК, ТРЦ, МТРЦ, ТЦ mean?